# Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь добавивший запись в БД, сам мог ее и удалить, через кнопку? Django 3

Tags: python, django, django-model

У меня есть профиль и в нем отображаются игры, которые добавил пользователь.

[image: Профиль]

Как сформировать get запрос на именно эту запись и удалить её с помощью кнопки?

Модель:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True, verbose_name='Название игры')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL вашей игры")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1', verbose_name='Кем добавлен')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name='Иконка игры (300x240)')
    game_files = models.FileField(upload_to="gamefiles/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name='Файлы игры', null=True)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Время публикации')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Опубликовать')
    gen = models.ForeignKey('Genre', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Жанр")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def profile_detail(request, username):
    profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    posts = Game.objects.filter(added_by=profile)
    deleted_game = Game.objects.get()
    deleted_game.delete()
    num_games = posts.count()

    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'game_list': posts,
        'num_games': num_games,
        'title': profile.username,
        'posts': posts,
        'menu': menu,
        'delete': deleted_game
    }
    return render(request, 'games_list/profile.html', context)
```